# Создать ref для элементов в цикле

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

У меня есть массив реакт элементов, который я вывожу с помощи функции `map`:

```
{ elemsList.map((item, i) => { 
    return (
        <div 
           key={i}
           ref={refsArr[i]}
           data-grid={item.props["data-grid"]}
           onClick={e => doubleClickHandler(item.key, e)}
           style={{ 
                backgroundColor: i === selectedComponent ? '#828EE3' : "#102f6a", 
                color: "#fff", 
                height: "100%",
           }}
        >
            {item}
        </div>
    )}
) }
```

Мне нужно создать `ref` для каждого из элементов этого массива. Я попробовал сделать это использовав `useRef`, передавая туда массив:

```
const refsArr = useRef([])
refsArr.current = elemsList.map((item, i) => refsArr.current[i] ?? setTimeout(createRef(), 5000))
...
{ elemsList.map((item, i) => { 
    return (
        <div 
           key={i}
           ref={refsArr[i]}
           data-grid={item.props["data-grid"]}
           onClick={e => doubleClickHandler(item.key, e)}
           style={{ 
                backgroundColor: i === selectedComponent ? '#828EE3' : "#102f6a", 
                color: "#fff", 
                height: "100%",
           }}
        >
            {item}
        </div>
    )}
) }
```

Проблема в том, что при попытке вывода моего `ref-массива` в консоль, вместо нормального `ref`, я получаю объект следующего содержания:

```
{ current: [53] }
```

Как можно исправить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

> Мне нужно создать ref для каждого из элементов этого массива.

Предложу такой вариант создания массива "рефов" для элементов другого массива...

```js
const arr = ['Один', 'Два', 'Три', 'Четыре']
//
function App() {
  const ref = Array.from({length: arr.length}, (_, i) => React.useRef())
  return <ul onClick={_ => console.log(ref[1].current)}>
    {arr.map((v, i) => <li key={v} ref={ref[i]}>{v}</li>)}
  </ul>
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
```